# qt binary file writing and reading

Tags: c++, qt, binary

```
void write(QString filename) {
  QChar ch('b');
  QFile mfile(filename);
  if (!mfile.open(QFile::WriteOnly) {
    qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
    return;
  }
  QDataStream out(&mfile);
  out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
  out << ch;
  mfile.close();
}
```

open binary file and writing 'b'(binary)

```
void read(QString filename) {
  QFile mfile(filename);
  if (!mfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Could not open file for reading";
    return;
  }
  QDataStream in(&mfile);
  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
  QChar mT;
  in >> mT;
  qDebug() << mT;
  mfile.close();
}
```

read but not mT='b'.if ch and mT variables are int always mT=4 why?How can i writing ch(binary file) and read from binary file

Comment: You need to open() the file for writing/reading.

Comment: Sorry i was writing code in my mind. i opened and not change problem still

Comment: what are the values returned by in.status(), and out.status()

Comment: Can you properly write your question? You just paste some code and expect people to answer in a proper way? Also, how can this ever help someone else with similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

the `4` number is the length of your data. `QDataStream` store length of your data before it to indicate how many bytes need to read to gain the written data. your data has been written after it.